# what is the size of reference variable in java

Tags: java

What is the size of reference variables in java? I am quite sure it wont be dependent upon the architecture or is it? Does it bear any resemblance with concept of pointers in C? I have tries but could not get any convincing answer.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350950/reference-type-size-in-java

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882277/how-to-find-objects-size-including-contained-objects

Comment: Size will be dependent on the architecture of the virtual machine.

Comment: What does it matter?  How would you tell if the reference is 32 bits or 64 or 128?  What difference could it possibly make in the execution of a program (other than the amount of heap required)?

Answer (score 13):

The amount of memory used by a reference depends on several parameters:

- on a 32-bit JVM, it will be 32 bits
- on a 64-bit JVM, it can be 32 or 64 bits depending on configuration. On hotspot for example, [compressed ordinary object pointers](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops) is activated by default and the size of a reference is 32 bits. If you deactivate the option with `-XX:-UseCompressedOops`, they will use 64 bits.

Comment: you can get `32 bits` references size even without `CompressedOops`, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62664346/1059372) for example