# Java object memory size of a set of strings

Tags: java, memory-management

I have a hash set of 1000 strings. Each string is having a size of 10.

Can you tell me the exact number of bytes required to store this in memory? Both for 32bit and 64bit VMs.

Can you explain the way to calculate this?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Shouldn't it not matter because `String` uses `char[]` internally and `size()` returns the length of that array?

Comment: If you want to find this out yourself you can use [`getObjectSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getObjectSize-java.lang.Object-) from the `Instrumentation` interface

Comment: @user3580294 Yeah, good point. (Please set your name. I keep confusing you with other users that just created their accounts.)

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if you can feasibly calculate this by hand... Object attributes are aligned on 8-byte borders, and some rearranging is done to save memory, and all in all it's a ton of work that I'm not sure too many people would want to do...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find Object's size (including contained objects)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882277/how-to-find-objects-size-including-contained-objects)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry about that, I'll get around to it when I come up with something not terrible...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because I have no life, I present the results of boredom. Note that this is pretty much guaranteed to be inaccurate, due stupid mistakes and such. Used [this](http://www.codeinstructions.com/2008/12/java-objects-memory-structure.html) for help, but I'm not too sure on accuracy. I *could* read the JVM specifications, but I don't have *that* much free time on my hands.

This calculation gets pretty complicated due to the multitude of fields that exist inside the objects of concern, plus some uncertainty on my part about how much overhead there is for objects and where padding goes. If memory serves, objects have 8 bytes reserved for the header. This is all for a 64-bit VM, by the way. Only difference between that and a 32-bit VM is the size of references, I think.

Summary of how to do this: Obtain source code, and recursively add up space needed for all fields. Need knowledge of how VM works and how implementations work.

Starting from a `String`. `String` defines:

1. Object header - 8 bytes
2. `long serialVersionUID` - 8 bytes
3. `int hash` - 4 bytes + 4 bytes padding
4. `char[] value` (set to a `char[10]` in your case) - 8 bytes for reference
5. `ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields = new ObjectStreamField[0]` - 8 bytes for reference

`char[10]` defines:

1. Object header - 8 bytes
2. `int length` - 4 bytes
3. `char` x10 - 2 bytes * 10 = 20 bytes

`ObjectStreamField[0]` defines:

1. Object header - 8 bytes
2. `int length` - 4 bytes + 4 bytes padding

Total for a single `String` with length 10: 88 bytes

Total for 1000 `String`s with length 10: 88000 bytes.

---

`HashSet` defines:

1. Object header - 8 bytes
2. `long serialVersionUID` - 8 bytes
3. `Object PRESENT` - 8 bytes
4. `HashMap<E, Object> map` - 8 bytes

`HashMap` defines (in Java 8) (ignoring things that are created on demand, like `EntrySet`):

1. Object header - 8 bytes
2. `long serialVersionUID` - 8 bytes
3. `int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY` - 4 bytes
4. `int MAXIMUM_CAPACITY` - 4 bytes
5. `int TREEIFY_THRESHOLD` - 4 bytes
6. `int UNTREEIFY_THRESHOLD` - 4 bytes
7. `int MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY` - 4 bytes
8. `int size` - 4 bytes
9. `int modcount` - 4 bytes
10. `int threshold` - 4 bytes
11. `float DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR` - 4 bytes
12. `float loadFactor` - 4 bytes
13. `Node<K, V>[] table` - 8 bytes

`Node` defines:

1. Object header - 8 bytes
2. `int hash` - 4 bytes + 4 bytes padding
3. `K key` - 8 bytes
4. `V value` - 8 bytes
5. `Node<K, V> next` - 8 bytes

`Node<K, V>[]` should have a size of 2048, if I remember how `HashMap` works. So it defines:

1. Object header - 8 bytes
2. `int length` - 4 bytes + 4 bytes padding
3. `Node<K, V>` reference * 2048 - 8 bytes * 2048 = 16384 bytes.

So the `HashSet` should be:

1. 32 bytes for just `HashSet`
2. 64 bytes for just `HashMap`
3. 40 bytes per `Node<K, V>` inside `Node<K, V>[]` * 1000 nodes = 40000 bytes
4. 16400 bytes for `Node<K, V>[]` inside the `HashMap`

Total: 56496 bytes for the `HashSet`, without taking into account the `String` contents

---

So at least by my calculations, the total space taken should be somewhere around 144496 bytes -- about 141 kilobytes (kibibytes for the pedantic). To be honest, this seems like it's more than a bit on the small side, but it's a start.

I can't get the `Instrumentation` interface working at the moment, so I can't double-check. But if someone knows what he/she is doing a comment pointing out my mistakes would be welcome.

Comment: If the Strings are not unique, they might be pooled and therefore use less space. This is up to the JVM implementation though.